# Unable to establish one-to-one relation with Sequelize

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I declared:

```
Item.hasOne(Item, { foreignKey: 'parentAid', as: 'Parent' })
```

I queried:

```
Item.find({where : {aid: aid}, include: [Item]}).complete(function(err, article) { .. };
```

And I get:

```
Error: Item is not associated to Item!
```

What am I doing wrong?

..............................................................................................

**UPDATE 1**

Thanks to the helpful answer by [Jan Aargaard Meier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/800016/jan-aagaard-meier), I was able to change things to:

```
ItemModel.belongsTo(ItemModel, { foreignKey: 'parentAid', as: 'Parent', foreignKeyConstraint: true });
ItemModel.hasMany(ItemModel, { as: 'Children', constraints: false });

this.articleRelations.push({
    model: ItemModel,
    as: 'Parent'
});

this.articleRelations.push({
    model: ItemModel,
    as: 'Children'
});

// ...
```

My query is now:

```
{where : {aid: aid}, include: this.articleRelations}
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
{
code : "ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR",
errno : 1054,
sqlState : "42S22",
index : 0,
sql : "SELECT `item`.*, `Parent`.`aid` AS `Parent.aid`, `Parent`.`gid` AS `Parent.gid`, `Parent`.`title` AS `Parent.title`, `Parent`.`type` AS `Parent.type`, `Parent`.`parentAid` AS `Parent.parentAid`, `Parent`.`createdAt` AS `Parent.createdAt`, `Parent`.`updatedAt` AS `Parent.updatedAt`, `Parent`.`itemId` AS `Parent.itemId`, `Parent`.`aid` AS `Parent.aid`, `Parent`.`aid` AS `Parent.aid`, `Parent`.`aid` AS `Parent.aid`, `Children`.`aid` AS `Children.aid`, `Children`.`gid` AS `Children.gid`, `Children`.`title` AS `Children.title`, `Children`.`type` AS `Children.type`, `Children`.`parentAid` AS `Children.parentAid`, `Children`.`createdAt` AS `Children.createdAt`, `Children`.`updatedAt` AS `Children.updatedAt`, `Children`.`itemId` AS `Children.itemId`, `Children`.`aid` AS `Children.aid`, `Children`.`aid` AS `Children.aid`, `Children`.`aid` AS `Children.aid` FROM (SELECT `item`.* FROM `item` WHERE `item`.`aid`=2 LIMIT 1) AS `item` LEFT OUTER JOIN `item` AS `Parent` ON `Parent`.`aid` = `item`.`parentAid` LEFT OUTER JOIN `item` AS `Children` ON `item`.`aid` = `Children`.`itemId`;"
```

}

Note:
 * The table name is `item`
 * The query contains `itemId`, which I did not define anywhere. That seems to be a bug?

For reference, this is my model:

```
ItemModel = sequelize.define('ExerciseItem', {
        aid: {type: Sequelize.INTEGER.UNSIGNED, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true},
        gid: {type: Sequelize.INTEGER.UNSIGNED},
        title: Sequelize.STRING(100),
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
        parentAid: Sequelize.INTEGER.UNSIGNED
    },{
        freezeTableName: true,
        tableName: 'item'
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Item.find({where : {aid: aid}, include: [{ model: Item, as: 'Parent' }])
```

If you give the relation an alias, you have to provide that alias when doing eager loading (just like you would call `getParent` instead of `getItem` on an item instance)

This is because aliasing (using `as`) allows you to create several associations to the same model, so when you just provide the model there is no way for sequelize to know which model you actually want to load.

We have been talking about the ability to using the return value from the relation call instead, something like:

```
var itemParentRelation = Item.hasOne(Item, { foreignKey: 'parentAid', as: 'Parent' })
Item.find({where : {aid: aid}, include: [itemParentRelation])
// or
Item.find({where : {aid: aid}, include: [item.relations.parent])
```

But for now you'll have to use the code provided in the beginning of the post :)

Comment: Thanks for your help! Can you check my updated problem statements? Should I file a bug?

Comment: Try adding a `foreignKey` to your hasMany call as well

Comment: This works great! Except... Sadly, the `where` restrictions propagate throughout the join. Can I somehow restrict `where` entries to some table or alias? E.g. if I have `var queryData = {where : {gid: gid, type: ItemType.Problem}, include: cat.component.childRelation};`, I only want the `where` to apply to the initial items, not to the children.

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean there? Could you perhaps update your issue or post on the sequelize bug tracker? https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues

Comment: I am still working on code related to it. Once it is done, I can test further and let you know!